# Can’t scale up nodes because node auto-provisioning is disabled, which prevents provisioning of node groups

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

All I have is a GKE cluster and there are 3 node pools and the machine size is `e2-standard-2` but when I push my deployment into this cluster I got this error on gke dashboard
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDVOl.png)

Although I have enabled the node auto-provisioning but it is still showing this error.
Can you help me out how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you are using `Standard GKE` not `Autopilot GKE`.

[Using node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning) GKE documentation provides much information about this feature.

Regarding your issue, you mention that your cluster didn't have `node auto-provisioning` and you have enabled it.
In [Enabling node auto-provisioning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#enable) part you have note:

> If you disable then re-enable auto-provisioning on your cluster, **existing node pools will not have auto-provisioning enabled. To re-enable auto-provisioning for these node pools, you need to** [mark individual node pools](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-provisioning#mark_node_auto-provisioned) as auto-provisioned.

In short, if you just enabled auto-provisioning on cluster using:

```
gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME \
    --enable-autoprovisioning \
    ... (other config)
```

**It will work for new node-pools.**

To enable `node auto-provisioning` for **already existing** `node-pools`, you need to specify it by name:

```
gcloud container node-pools update NODE_POOL_NAME \
  --enable-autoprovisioning
```

If you didn't change anything, the first `node-pool` in the new cluster by default is called `default-pool`. So for example you should use

```
gcloud container node-pools update default-pool \
  --enable-autoprovisioning
```

If this won't solve your issue, please provide more details about your cluster, what commands you execute in order to replicate this behavior.